# Icons not showing on Laravel project but showing on HTML Template

Tags: html, css, laravel

Icons are not showing after I put the HTML in the blade but are showing on the HTML Template. Since the files were under node_modules, knowing it would not make much of a difference I still tried using `npm install`. I have attached the CSS and Blade below followed by a screenshot of the output.

[image]

```
CSS
@font-face {
    font-family: themify;
    src: url({{ asset('admin_assets/icons/themify-icons/fonts/themify.eot@-fvbane') }});
    src: url({{ asset('admin_assets/icons/themify-icons/fonts/themify.eot@') }})
            format("embedded-opentype"),
        url({{ asset('admin_assets/icons/themify-icons/fonts/themify.woff') }})
            format("woff"),
        url({{ asset('admin_assets/icons/themify-icons/fonts/themify.ttf') }})
            format("truetype"),
        url({{ asset('admin_assets/icons/themify-icons/fonts/themify.svg@-fvbane') }})
            format("svg");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I can't seen to understand where the problem is. I looked up on the internet and many places says I also have to use {{ asset('') }} in CSS files as well. But with or without, it made no difference.

Comment: normally when you refer a font path inside a css or scss file in resources folder  as a font family definition  laravel mix copies those files from node_modules into public/fonts folder then it will re-write those paths to use /fonts.As an example when you install font awesome and import font-awesome.scss laravel mix copies all font files to the public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at your code above I am going make the following assumptions:

1. You are including the snippet above which defines your font class and the path to the assets in a blade template file within a  block and it not compiled.
2. You are trying to access files that located most likely within the `node_modules` within your app using the `asset('...')` helper tag. (I am guessing something like `node_modules/admin_assets/icons/themify-icons/fonts/ ...`.)

The issues as I would understand it given the assumptions above is that the helper tag `asset()` helper tag cannot access the node_modules in-line and the `asset()` serves relative from the `public` folder in your project.

With that being said you will either need to manually copy the files where you want in the public folder and call them. You can still use the helper tag.

Or, you can in your `webpack.mix.js` file using `npm run dev` to build it you can copy the files in your build from the node_modules folder with something like:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

...


mix.copy('node_modules/admin_assets/icons/themify-icons/fonts', 'public/fonts');

...
```

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#copying-files-and-directories
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset

I hope that helps and explains what is happening.